# Windows 7 system sounds disabled/wont play

Tags: windows-7, system-sounds

I am using Windows 7 pro 64 and am having a problem where none of the system sounds will play. All other audio seems to be working as per usual; it is only the system sounds that aren't working.

I went to the `Sounds` settings window and when I hit the "Test" button for various sounds, nothing plays. So, I ran `sfc /scannow` but all my files were fine, so I created a new user and logged into the new account, and all the sounds were playing fine. Also, if I go to the .wav file on my main account (problem account) it plays fine in windows media player.

I'm not sure what else to do, I must have some setting that I can't find disabling the system sounds or something.

Comment: Go into the speaker icon in the notification area and choose "Mixer". Is the "System Sounds" slider muted or all the way down?

Comment: @Randolph West: lol yes. Thank you. Post as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose that your "System Sounds" setting is muted, or all the way down.

You can get there by clicking on the speaker icon in the notification area, choosing `Mixer`, and looking at the `System Sounds` option there, under `Applications`.

[image: Choose mixer]
[image: Fix muted value]

Comment: I can't believe this was my issue. Wow. Good catch.

Comment: Yeah, me too - I wonder how this happens?